# Application Blocked by Java Security to run a JNLP File in OS X Sierra(10.12)

Tags: java, jnlp, macos-sierra

I have tried to run a .jnlp file. But it is blocked by Java Security showing following message.
"Application Blocked by Java Security."

Java Version: Java 8 Update 102.
OS X: Sierra (10.12)
JNLP File Link: https://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=applet&d2=full-support

Comment: Not a programming question. Please move this to [su]

Answer (score 1):

The java security settings are requiring that every jar in the jnlp file needs a valid and non expired (or with timestamp) certificate.

Checking a jar from your jnlp file with the jarsigner command

```
jarsigner -verify arena-client-7.1.3.jar
```

returns:

```
jar verified.

Warning:  This jar contains entries whose signer certificate has expired.
This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated. This
jar contains signatures that does not include a timestamp. Without a 
timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer 
certificate's expiration date (2016-03-26) or after any future revocation date.
```

And there is your problem.